# Cant see wall posts via facebook graph api on business page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I created a business page on Facebook and using the graph api Im trying to post wall posts to this business page via the api/php. I created the facebook app with another account and gave the app permission to post to the business page. I then used the api call to post a message to the business page wall and the api does give me back a wall post id but I dont see the post on the business page from another facebook account. I pressed the like button for that business page and still dont see any posts.

The kicker is though if I log into facebook as the business page account and view the page I see every wall post I posted via the graph api/php call I made. So the posts are going through its just everyone outside the business page cant see the post. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please post the code of posting on the business wall from another application(account)? how can you post to the business wall if you don't have its access token? and if you have , how did you get the access token from the company page ? thank :)

Comment: @Rodniko: http://blog.codovations.com/2011/04/tutorial-post-data-on-facebook-company.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding a business account and a regular friend account are 2 different types of facebook accounts. If you want to post on a friends wall all you need is permission to do so, if you want to post on a business page you need to be granted manage_pages to the business account. This will then allow you to query /me/accounts to get all pages that account manages and the access token for each page. From there you can ask the person which page you want to post to, depending on which page you grab the access token for that page. Facebook makes this a pain in the butt and very restrictive when it comes to a business page and a friends page. It should all just be the same. Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your business page and click on settings.

You will be able to select an option to view all wall posts rather than the default option of only those posts submitted from the page.